# MYSQL pass stored procedure variable IN clause

Tags: mysql

How can I query comma separated dynamic ids in `where` clause `IN` function?

SET @status_ids = '1,3';

```
SELECT story_title, description FROM tbl_story WHERE story_status_id IN (@status_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function.

```
SET @status_ids = '1,3';
SELECT story_title, description FROM tbl_story WHERE FIND_IN_SET(story_status_id, @status_ids) > 0;
```